# Image not shown in the theme as it's showing in HTML template

Tags: images, css

I'm working on a theme creation in WordPress. When I add `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` before an image tag, it didn't work, and also I gave image url in .css file

```
#about-bg-diagonal {


     width: 60%;
     height: 700%;
     float: right;
     background-image: url(../img/bg-about.jpg);
     border-left: 200px solid white;
     border-top: 700px solid transparent;

 }
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your question is, but this sounds like a CSS question moreso than a WordPress question. Have you inspected the element to see whether the image is loading? Typically you need to specify more of the path if you are including an image in your CSS because the website will look in its own relative path rather than your theme's path.